# Fill a column according to a weight list in another Spark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have:

Dataframe A

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Null |
| 2 | Null |
| 3 | Null |
| 4 | Null |

Dataframe B

| Name | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 0.5 |
| Mike | 0.25 |
| John | 0.25 |

I need to fill (in PySpark) the column "Name" (Dataset A) according to the weighted Name of Dataset B:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Max |
| 2 | Max |
| 3 | Mike |
| 4 | John |

Max 50%; Mike 25%; John 25%

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best approach, but it would work for weights >= 0.01. I wanted to create an approach where equality would be used in the `join` as opposed to > < >= and <=.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
dfA = spark.range(1, 5).toDF("ID")
dfB = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Max', 0.5),
     ('Mike', 0.25),
     ('John', 0.25)],
    ['Name', 'weight'])
```

Script:

```py
cs = F.round(F.sum('weight').over(W.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, 0)), 2)
dfB = dfB.withColumn('w', F.sequence(((cs - F.col('weight'))*100+1).cast('int'), (cs*100).cast('int')))
dfB = dfB.withColumn('w', F.explode('w'))

cntA = dfA.count()
dfA = dfA.withColumn('w', F.ceil(F.count('ID').over(W.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, 0))/cntA*100))

dfA = dfA.join(dfB, 'w', 'left').drop('w', 'weight')

dfA.show()
# +---+----+
# | ID|Name|
# +---+----+
# |  1| Max|
# |  2| Max|
# |  3|Mike|
# |  4|John|
# +---+----+
```